# Using ECMAScript 6 In Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm sure this is a simple one - But I'm learning Javascript and executing programs through Node.js

```
function sumAll(arr) {

   var max = Math.max(...arr);
   console.log(max);

}

sumAll([1, 4]);
```

The error I have is:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

I assume this is down to the ES6 spread operator?
Is this not valid?

I have also tried to add the following, based on other StackOverflow answers I've found:

```
"use strict";
```

But this doesn't work either.

Any help appreciated - Thanks

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: `->` http://node.green/

Comment: FYI, `...` [is not an operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37152508/218196).

Comment: @FelixKling - How should I refer to "..." when speaking with other developers?

Comment: Depends on the context. See the link in my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that you use outdated node.js version. Try to update your node.js to the latest version.

Comment: Simple - I was running v4.4.2
Upgrading to v.6.9.1 solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

Might be you are using outdated node.js version. Try to update your node.js with v6.10 or later on the latest version.